# Linux - How to toggle sloppy mouse window using terminal / hotkeys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, linux-mint

So I can change window focus mode using the GUI but I would like to be able to switch between sloppy and click on toggle and want to create a script for that that is trigger by keyboard.

However, can't find a working solution. Tried:

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/general/focus_mode sloppy

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'sloppy'
```

None would activate it when it was on click when run from terminal.

Whatever the GUI is doing, I should be able to do as well.

[image]

Comment: Which DE/WM are you using? Mint used to use Cinnamon, and had MATE & XFCE versions? XFCE has very easy keyboard shortcuts for anything you can type in it's settings -> Keyboard -> shortcuts tab. Does your terminal command change the GUI setting, but has no effect when run from a regular terminal?

Comment: I am using linux mint, cinnamon. There is a setting in UI but can't find in the shortcuts. I can set one up myself, but what is the command to change this setting?